# ui-router problems with query string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have these states:

```
.state('message', {
  url : '/message'
  templateUrl : 'views/message.html',
  controller : 'messageController'
})
.state('news', {
  url : '/news'
  templateUrl: 'views/news.html',
  controller : 'newsController'
})
```

In `messageController` i append some query string in url like `/message?contact=some`.

problem is that when go to news state with `ui-sref`, query strings does not cleared and it redirects to `/news?contact=some`.

i tried to clear `$location.search` in `stateChangeEvent`.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following:

**Use query params:**

```
 .state('message', {
     url: "/message?contact"
     // will match to url of "/message?contact=value"
     ...
 }
```

**Use state params: (better for ui-sref linking)**

```
.state('message', {
    url: "/message/:contact",
    // can be accessed by $stateParams service - $stataParams['contact']
    ...
 }
```